# How to show and hide a div on a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some item that show in list view. I want when someone click in one of the item it will show him a div under of it with the option like price, quantity and other. I just want to know how to make hid div that will not show until the user click in one of the item.

Like the one in YouTube when you watch a video you can see share button down of it. If you click on it, it will show u new window down of it to choose where to share and other option.

My code

```
<ul data-role="listview">


  <?php do { ?>
        <li><a href="product_option.php?pr=<?php echo $row_productDaa['idProct']; ?>"><img src="../document/product/<?php echo $row_productDta['strIage']; ?>" alt="" border="0"/>
        <p style="font-size:18px"><php echo $row_productDaa['strProctName']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $row_productData['dblPce']; ?>$</p>
        <div> <p><?php echo $row_productata['strO']; ?></p></div></a>
        </li>
          <?php } while ($row_productata = mysql_fetch_assoc($prodctDaata)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the click event to something like this:

```
jQuery('#the_hidden_stuff').show();
```

So it could look like this:

```
<div id="clicker">Clicker</div>
<div id="the_hidden_stuff" style="display: none;">
    Something to show when clicker is clicked.
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#clicker').click(function() {
            jQuery('#the_hidden_stuff').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

See: [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for more examples.

Comment: i didn't get it . can u give me example